# Horizontal oriented Feynman diagram with loop is not produced horizontal

Tags: tikz-feynman, horizontal

I tried to make a simple first order loop diagram of a photon with a virtual fermion loop. This works, except from the last horizontal photon (wavy) line. This is the syntax I used with the `tikz-feynman` package (with option `[compat=1.1.0]`):

```
\documentclass{report}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
   \usepackage{mathtools}
   \usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman} 

   \begin{document}
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:fermionloop}
    i\pi_{\mu\nu}^{ab}(q) =
    \begin{gathered}
    \feynmandiagram [scale=2][layered layout, horizontal=a to b]{
    a [particle={\(\gamma\)}, scale=1]  -- [photon,  momentum=\(q\)] c
     -- [fermion, half left, looseness=1.5, momentum=\(k+q\)] d
     -- [fermion, half left, looseness=1.5, momentum=\(k\)] c,
    d -- [photon, momentum=\(q\)] b
    }; \end{gathered} 
    %= i\pi_{\mu \nu}^{ab} (q)
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

And the result is:

[image]

How could I get a horizontal photon line at the end?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: If you use `horizontal=a to b` it works, as expected.

Comment: No sorry, I changed the second point many times and it doesn't work with any of them

Comment: Your minimal example works for me, I suspect the reason it isn't working for you is because you aren't compiling with LuaLaTeX.  Try that and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Yes, with LuaLaTeX the single diagram works! But in my thesis it produces errors that I cannot solve by looking at current discussions. Is there a good description of using LuaLaTeX with texmaker on mac?

Comment: I still did not manage to produce a horizontal wavy line at the right. Compiling with LuaLatex does not work, while I did add \RequirePackage{luatex85} and \usepackage{luatex85} in the preamble. I can not find a clear explanation of how to compile with LuaLatex just in TexMaker. Could anyone help me further with this?